# NoSuchMethodError with FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()

Tags: java, android

My app crashes when I'm trying to save data in a Firebase database. The error shows on this line:

```
databaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
```

The stack trace:

```
08-24 00:24:16.275 11091-11091/com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem, PID: 11091
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.addaj.mobilerecommendationsystem.RegistrationActivity.onCreate(RegistrationActivity.java:60)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6860)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2674)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Comment: You have to provide more information please to specify your problem as much as possible, so it's easier to find the issue!

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: What information should I provide? Can you pls guide me Joe S?

Comment: My apps crash because of the getInstance()

Comment: can you show the full code?

Comment: I cant paste all the coding here. Popup will display, "You enter too many code".... Can I share the coding throught the email ?

Comment: check out my answer , does it works for u ?

Comment: yes , hasanbadran88@gmail.com

Comment: can you post the log?

Comment: Show the log, please

Comment: I already email you sir.

Comment: You need to provide the relevant information in the question here.

Comment: Okay i already edit my question with the logcat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to make firebase libraries version the same ex :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
```

or choose any version you want like 16.0.1 check out firebase release notes: [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Comment: Its work sir! I just need to change my database version. Thanks!

Comment: oh that's great :) i am happy that it worked... feel free to upvote